# Select Statement with dropdown list issue

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a quick question to ask..
But ill make an example first
Column1 is MemberID
Column2 is Teamname

MemberID = 23, Teamname = ggdiablo

I have made a dropdown list of my teamname column..

```
<select id="teamlist" name="teamlist">
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select MemberID, teamname from members where ');
$stmt->execute();

   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo "<option>".$row['teamname']."</option>";
 }
 ?>
</select>
```

is it possible to automatically fill in MemberID in a textbox form if I choose "ggdiablo" from the dropdown list?
if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript. Add a value attribute for each  tag, with the MemberID. Add a onchange attribute to the  tag, with the following value: `onChangeTeamListSelect();`. Fix your code, you are missing an opening  tag.

```
 function onChangeTeamListSelect()
 {
    var objSelectTeamlist=document.getElementById('teamlist');
    var objEditBox=document.getElementById('some_edit_box_id');

    objEditBox.value=objSelectTeamlist.value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you just need to do some javascripting. Try looking at [this](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

It's really very simple using jQuery. Please find below code.

```
$("#teamlist").live("change",function(){
   $("#txtBox").val($(this).val());
});
```

PS: You can ignore "live" if you are not creating dropdown using ajax(dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

Is possible with jquery:

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/JellyBelly/HY3Bh/3/

**html:**

```
<select name='foo' id="foo">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='X'>Desc X</option>
    <option value='Y'>Desc Y</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" value=""/>
```

**​and jquery**

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
    $("#bar").val($(this).val());
});​
```

very simple! ;)